# MLP classifier results in different models using almost identical data

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, mlp

I am simulating soccer predictions using scikit-learns MLP classifier. Two model trainings using almost identical data (the second one contains 42 more rows out of 5466 total) and configuration (e.g. random_state) results in the below statistics:

```
2020-09-19 00:00:00
-------------------------------------------MLPClassifier--------------------------------------------
Fitting 3 folds for each of 27 candidates, totalling 81 fits

GridSearchCV:
Best score : 0.5179227897048015
Best params: {'classifier__alpha': 2.4, 'classifier__hidden_layer_sizes': [3, 3], 'preprocessor__num__scaling': StandardScaler(), 'selector': SelectFromModel(estimator=RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=10,
                                                 random_state=42),
                threshold='2.1*median'), 'selector__threshold': '2.1*median'}

              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           A       0.59      0.57      0.58      1550
           D       0.09      0.47      0.15       244
           H       0.82      0.57      0.67      3143

    accuracy                           0.57      4937
   macro avg       0.50      0.54      0.47      4937
weighted avg       0.71      0.57      0.62      4937

2020-09-26 00:00:00
-------------------------------------------MLPClassifier--------------------------------------------
Fitting 3 folds for each of 27 candidates, totalling 81 fits

GridSearchCV:
Best score : 0.5253689104507783
Best params: {'classifier__alpha': 2.4, 'classifier__hidden_layer_sizes': [3, 3], 'preprocessor__num__scaling': StandardScaler(), 'selector': SelectFromModel(estimator=RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=10,
                                                 random_state=42),
                threshold='1.6*median'), 'selector__threshold': '1.6*median'}

              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           A       0.62      0.57      0.59      1611
           D       0.00      0.00      0.00         0
           H       0.86      0.57      0.69      3336

    accuracy                           0.57      4947
   macro avg       0.49      0.38      0.43      4947
weighted avg       0.78      0.57      0.66      4947
```

How is that possible, that one model never predicts D, while the other one does? I am trying to understand, what's going here. I am afraid, posting the whole problem/code is not possible, so I am looking for a generic answer.  I have this behaviour (D's <-> no D's) throughout 38 observations.